# How to store the JComboBox item in 2 variables?

Tags: select, hashmap, key, jcombobox

I have a Jcombo box that is populated by an hashmap(each JComboBox item is equal with an hashmap object - is formatted by 2 values:one key and one value).
When I use getSelectedItem() - return something like that : key=value ;

I need to store the key in one variable and the value in another variable .

How can I do this? Does there exist an alternarive for JComboBox to store 2 values for each item of JComboBox ?

Answer (score 1):

As I got your question. Here is a very simple JComboBox class. You can understand the process by reading the code and modify as you wish

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class JComboBoxPair<K, E> extends JComboBox<E> {

private ArrayList<Object> key_array;

public JComboBoxPair() {
    this.key_array = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void setModel(Map<String, String> map) {
    DefaultComboBoxModel boxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(map.values().toArray());
    super.setModel(boxModel);
    key_array.clear();
    key_array = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
}

public String[] getSelectedItemInfoArray() {
    String[] ar = new String[2];
    ar[0] = key_array.get(super.getSelectedIndex()).toString();
    ar[1] = super.getSelectedItem().toString();
    return ar;
}

@Override
public String getSelectedItem() {
    return super.getSelectedItem().toString();
}

public String getSelectedKey() {
    return key_array.get(super.getSelectedIndex()).toString();
}

}
```